# Call a controller method without a slash in the context root

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I try to creating an API with Spring Boot. Spring Boot's version is as follows

```
spring-boot 1.5.13.RELEASE
spring-core 4.3.17.RELEASE
```

The context root is set to "/hoge" and "application.properties",

```
server.context-path=/hoge
```

and the
Controller methods are as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String default(
                HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response,
                SessionStatus sStatus,
                Model model, Locale locale) throws IOException, Exception {
        return login(request, response, sStatus, model, locale);
}
```

The following was executed in curl and the method was executed.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/hoge/
```

However, without the trailing slash below, the method did not execute.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/hoge
```

The method could not be executed when the value in the method's RequestMapping annotation was

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"","/"})
```

I would like to know how to execute a method on a request without trailing slash.

Thank you in advance.

---

Appendix

ex1(Could not execute.)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "")
public class TestAction {

     public String default(
             HttpServletRequest request,
             HttpServletResponse response,
             SessionStatus sStatus,
             Model model, Locale locale) throws IOException, Exception {
         return login(request, resonse, sStatus, model, locale);
     }
}
```

ex2(Could not execute.)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "*")
public class TestAction {

     public String default(
             HttpServletRequest request,
             HttpServletResponse response,
             SessionStatus sStatus,
             Model model, Locale locale) throws IOException, Exception {
         return login(request, resonse, sStatus, model, locale);
     }
}
```

ex3(Could not execute.)

```
@Controller
public class TestAction {
     @RequestMapping(value = "")
     public String default(
             HttpServletRequest request,
             HttpServletResponse response,
             SessionStatus sStatus,
             Model model, Locale locale) throws IOException, Exception {
         return login(request, resonse, sStatus, model, locale);
     }
}
```

ex4(Could not execute.)

```
@Controller
public class TestAction {
     @RequestMapping(value = "*")
     public String default(
             HttpServletRequest request,
             HttpServletResponse response,
             SessionStatus sStatus,
             Model model, Locale locale) throws IOException, Exception {
         return login(request, resonse, sStatus, model, locale);
     }
}
```

Comment: can you show me the key in the application.properties?

Comment: @JoonseoLee  this. server.context-path=/hoge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`server.context-path=/hoge` is just the context path. That is not the resource. Your resource is set to "`/`" at the moment (check request mapping). You haven't set a proper name for your resource.

To fix this you have to name your request mapping with something like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/default")
```

I have chosen "default" as the name here. You can name it however you want, as long as it is according to the standards.

And this is what the request would look like.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/hoge/default
```

If you don't want the context as `hoge` then remove the `server.context-path` property. Then your request would look like this.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/default
```

If you create another resource you can set it's request mapping to something like this, with a different name.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/default-new")
```

Which will result in a request like this.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/default-new
```

Comment: Thanks reply. I think that the resource name cannot be set to empty. Is this correct?  For example @RequestMapping(value = "")

Comment: As far as I know, you can have @RequestMapping at the controller level and have an empty mapping for your resource. Which will default it. But If you have multiple resources in your Controller, you should have unique name paths so Spring Boot can identify them.

Comment: Thank you. I tried running @RequestMapping on the class and method respectively, but none of them could trigger the method.
Please refer to the Appendix in the body of the document.

Comment: You have to have the @RequestMapping for both class level and method level. In the class level you can have it as `@RequestMapping("/hoge")`. In the method level have it as `@RequestMapping("")`. Try this and see.

Comment: Also, I don't see why you need to do this. If can tell me your exact requirement, I could provide you with a proper solution. Above answers are just my attempt to help you with the issues at hand rather than the proper solution to your exact need. So yeah, if you can give me your clear requirement, I can help you out.

Comment: Thank you.
I was able to call the method using the method you taught me. However, it seems that my question was not the right one.
I will close this question for now.